# Couchbase lite android - What is synchronized and what is not?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite

When we sync our local couchbase database in android with the server, what is exactly being synced? Do we have control over what can be synced and what not? 
Right now I give the sync URl and Couchbase syncs the whole database (`rather documents with appropriate channels to the android application`). Is there any **other** way of controlling which data is synced?
Also are views created on the server synced to the mobile application as well? If not, is there a way to replicate the server view as well to the mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question first, views are not replicated, as they're part of the app installed on the mobile device.  This makes sense as the indexes you have for the set of data is really a function of how the app is going to use it.  Also, views on Couchbase Mobile are typically implemented in the native language ([Android](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/get-started/get-started-mobile/android/index.html), [iOS](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/get-started/get-started-mobile/ios/index.html), [Xamarin C# or Unity](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/get-started/get-started-mobile/net-mobile/index.html)).

Regarding sync, channels are the primary way to filter down what's going to be sync'd to a device.  Since they can be added either [declaratively](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/sync-gateway/channels/developing/index.html#using-a-channels-property) or [programmatically in a sync function](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/sync-gateway/channels/developing/index.html#using-a-sync-function), it's pretty flexible.  What other way might you be seeking?

Comment: I tried filtering based on channels. So, whenever a user logs into my app, I change the sync url and only the appropriate documents pertaining to the user's channels are retrieved.  BUT when the current user logs out and a new user logs in (technically a new sync url and a new channel) - the old data is still there. The documents that were only for the eyes of the old user, are now visible to the new user as well.

Comment: This is probably happening because the same Couchbase Lite database is used for different users logging in and out. Two possible workarounds: 1) delete the content of the database when the user logs out with `database.delete()`. That way, when the next user logs in, the database will be empty. 2) choose a different database for each user. For example, choose the user’s id in your app as the name of the database. See the ToDoLite Android app for an [example](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/ToDoLite-Android/blob/master/ToDoLite/src/main/java/com/couchbase/todolite/Application.java#L358-L373)